# How to post .xlsx file to web api using Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have a requirement where **admin user** will upload .xlsx file which contains columns related to new user **Name, Age, Gender**.

On click of upload button, I need to post excel file to WEB API and save the data to SQL server.

I am using Angular 2, If anyone has an idea please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This plunker has resolved my issue. If anyone has the same problem please go through that.

    http://plnkr.co/edit/rYC3nd7undqJz2mr8Old?p=preview

Comment: The mentioned plunker uses [SheetJS](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx), which can read xlsx files in pure JavaScript.

Comment: js-xlsx, can also do the same thing @Oliver.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an Injectable Service for file upload and then simply call it from component. Below is the code:

**Service**

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
@Injectable()
export class FileUploadService {
 fileUpload(url: string, files: File[])
    : Promise<any> {
    progress$: any;
    progressObserver: any;
    progress: any;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
            xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("FileUpload", files[i], files[i].name);
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                } else {
                    reject(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
            this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
            this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
        };
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
}
```

**Component**

```
constructor(private fileUploadService: FileUploadService) {
}
this.fileUploadService.fileUpload(this.postURL,this.files)
            .then(dcDetailResponse => this.resetForm(dcDetailResponse))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

then at API controller(c#), change it as per your needs:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UploadDCDetail()     
 {
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
     {
      }
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Mansi, I have tried that but end up with some errors.
Please check this one "http://plnkr.co/edit/rYC3nd7undqJz2mr8Old?p=preview"

Comment: @Sagar, In the plunker you are using angularjs and I have posted code for angular2. Also you have asked question for Angular2. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: your code is perfectly working, I have found another way to get the job done. So I thought to let you know about that way too.

Comment: Your code is works for me. I was stucked since from three days you really helped me out. Thank you so much